# Matlab: cut data-array in smaller arrays

Tags: matlab, matrix

This is my matrix.

```
mat = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14]
```

Now I want to produce four new matrices.

```
mat1 = [1;5;9;13]
mat2 = [2;6;10;14]
mat3 = [3;7;11]
mat4 = [4;8;12]
```

Which command can I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mat1 = mat(1:4:end);
mat2 = mat(2:4:end);
mat3 = mat(3:4:end);
mat4 = mat(4:4:end);
```

Edit:  To address the comment, to make it slightly more general, I would use cell arrays and do something like

```
for i = 1:n,
     submat{i} = mat(i:n:end);
end
```

Comment: Best and most simple solution for four matrices. If it's more, `reshape()` could be worth a look, but you need to fill the missing places first...